# Xcode 6 iOS8 error: app containing framework must support arm64. My app already supports arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, ios8, arm64

I have an app who has arm64 in the valid architecutes. This app is iOS8 only.
I have a dynamic framework inside the project who supports arm64 too.

The app compile and runs without warnings both on simulator and real device.
When I archive (so Release deployment), I get this warning:

> warning: skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/claudio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-fysafeblgqwxvydddohezmdaqvbg/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/TSModel.framework/TSModel

If I try to submit the app for the AppStore, instead I get his error:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid architecture: Apps that include an app extension and a framework must support arm64

I don't know how to solve this problem.

It seems that there are other people with a similar problem to mine [ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid architecture: Apps that include an app extension and a framework must support arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935895/error-itms-9000-invalid-architecture-apps-that-include-an-app-extension-and-a)

Comment: Does the TSModel.framework actually get built for 64 bit? I.E., what does `lipo -info TSModel.framework/Versions/Current/TSModel` say? Is that framework actually making it into the .ipa package?

Comment: I am not trying to build a universal framework like in this case http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/12/13/building-a-universal-framework-for-ios/ So I am not executing "lipo -info ...". Shouldn't it work as is?

Comment: If you are including it in your app, it must support 64 bit. If lipo does not indicate that the framework has support for ARM 64 bit architecture, your app will get bounced by the checks for that.

Comment: I am not sure where/when I am supposed to run 'lipo'. Sorry but the framework thing is pretty new to me.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same problem. I am using about 3 frameworks so I need to work out which one is causing the issue, I have no idea how to do this...

Comment: I opted to remove the frameworks, since I was not able to find a solution...

Comment: Start a terminal window and move to the directory where your framework is. Say your framework, Blah.framework, is in /Users/jolly/projects/garf/dependencies/. You launch Terminal and enter:

`cd /Users/jolly/projects/garf/dependencies/`

then you query the architecture(s) of the framework with

`lipo -info Blah.framework/Versions/Current/Blah`